# print date of the folder by php  

Tags: php, date

I use this code to list the directories.

```
$files = glob('back/1/*',GLOB_ONLYDIR);

foreach ($files as $f){
    $tmp[basename($f)] = filemtime($f);
}

arsort($tmp);
$files = array_keys($tmp);

foreach($files as $folder){
    echo $folder;
}
```

But I want to print the date of the creation of the dir, how could I do that?

Comment: when you start learning yourself, dude? you can't ask here for the every piece of code you need!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you need to call `filemtime` (or `filectime` for creation time) whenever you print the file/directory name. You already do that to fill the `$tmp` array, which your sorting is based on. All you need to do now, is to print out the value of the `$tmp` array in your final loop where you print out the folder names.

For example like this:

```
foreach($files as $folder){
    $date = date( 'd.m.Y H:i', $tmp[$folder] );
    echo $folder . ' (' . $date . ')';
}
```

If you want to print out the *creation* time but still sort on the modification time, you can simply call `filectime` in the loop instead. Note however that you need to reconstruct the original pathname, as you used `basename` on the path before.

```
foreach($files as $folder){
    $date = date( 'd.m.Y H:i', filectime( 'back/1/' . $folder ) );
    echo $folder . ' (' . $date . ')';
}
```